AWS Redshift parallel query issue in Glue script
I have created a Glue script which is supposed to read data from Redshift. The code works perfectly without hash partitions although as soon as I try to run parallel queries it throws an error like this:
Caused by: com.amazon.redshift.util.RedshiftException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"

It's a huge error apart from this line which points me towards create_dynamic_frame.from_options in the end
Here's the snippet in question:
    query = f"""
        SELECT 
            DISTINCT id as id_list 
        FROM test_db.public.test_table 
        WHERE timestamp BETWEEN {start} AND {end} AND"""
    # Get list of ids from Redshift
    redshift_data_frame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        connection_type="redshift",
        connection_options={
            "sampleQuery": query,
            "redshiftTmpDir": args["TempDir"],
            "useConnectionProperties": "true",
            "connectionName": "redshift-conn", 
            "enablePartitioningForSampleQuery": True,
            "hashfield": "day",
            "hashpartitions": str(end_date), # Last day of month
            "aws_iam_role": args["AWS_IAM_ROLE"],
        },
        additional_options={"aws_iam_role": args["AWS_IAM_ROLE"]},
        transformation_ctx="redshift_data_frame",
    )



The same parallel queries work correctly in my other script which connects to SQL via JDBC:
    query = f"""
            SELECT 
                user_id 
            FROM 
                test_table 
            WHERE 
                id='{id}' AND timestamp BETWEEN {start} AND {end} AND"""
    
    db_data_frame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        connection_type="mysql",
        connection_options={
            "url": jdbc_url,
            "user": "username",
            "password": "pass",
            "dbtable": "test_db",
            "sampleQuery": query,
            "enablePartitioningForSampleQuery": True,
            "hashfield": "day",
            "hashpartitions": str(end_date), #last day of month
            "redshiftTmpDir": args["TempDir"],
        },
        transformation_ctx="db_data_frame",
    )

I am not that experienced with Glue and pyspark, it's been like a couple of months since I have jumped into all this hence I feel there's something small that I might have missed, although I have been following the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/run-jdbc-parallel-read-job.html.
Any help would be appreciated!

Do you have the ability to check the Redshift logging table to see the actual SQL issued?  I suspect if you see what is being issued you can find the issue quickly.

I could only see query logs but was not able to find my query there, I feel it never reached Redshift. Will confirm about the other logs with the team tomorrow
